# Primefaces datatable in tabview

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable, tabview

I have two class: park places and cars. The park has an id and a list of cars. I want to show the parking places with tabs and the list of the cars in a datatable. The problem is that i can't reach the car's plate number inside the datable. When i try to autocomplete in Netbeans it shows the park fields (the park id and the list of cars) for possibilites. Why? Any ideas how to fix it?

```
<p:tabView value="#{parkView.parks}" var="p">
            <p:tab title="Car Park #{p.id}">
                <p:dataTable var="c" value="#{p.cars}">
                    <p:column headerText="Parking Cars">
                        <h:outputText value="#{c.regPlateNumber}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable> 
            </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

Comment: `The problem is that i can't reach the car's plate number inside the datable` an example will be welcome

Comment: Give an example to clarify the question.

Answer (score 1):

I just guess and I'm unable to create comments (low reputation). Check the getter/setter methods of the car.plate (?) field. They should be public, non static and created by according to the bean property naming conventions.